# How to add views to LinearLayout, but from bottom upwards?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

It is possible to add views to `LinearLayout` one after another in upward direction?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can add it programmatically with:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
layout.addView(newView, index);
```

You just have to add always with index = 0

Is this the answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add views to LinearLayout in upward direction(i.e. from bottom to up) use

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

property in the xml of LinearLayout and then add  views in the layout.
Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: If I have only one view that does not fill my layout vertically, would it be displayed at the top end or the bottom end?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep your views top, relativelayout is another choice.