# Dynamic UI - How to add 3 linearlayouts into a parent linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic

I'm having a little bit of trouble with creating a dynamic UI.
I can get it to work with just one LinearLayout but I have no idea how to add more.

This is what I have now, it's one LinearLayout with 3 buttons.

Here is the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        maakLayout();
    }

    private void maakLayout() {
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        setContentView(linearLayout);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Button button = new Button(this);
            button.setText("Test");
            button.setTag(i);
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_red);



            LayoutParams layoutTextParams = new LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            // LayoutParams layoutImageParams =
            // new LayoutParams(100,100);
            layoutTextParams.topMargin = 5;
            layoutTextParams.leftMargin = 5;
            layoutTextParams.rightMargin = 5;
            button.setLayoutParams(layoutTextParams);

            linearLayout.addView(button);
        }
    }
```

What I need is the following:
[image: What I need]
And the static XML code for this is the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_red"
        android:text="Test" />

        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_red"
        android:text="Test" />

        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_red"
        android:text="Test" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="144dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/border_blue"
        android:text="Test" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_red"
        android:text="Test" />

        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_red"
        android:text="Test" />

        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_red"
        android:text="Test" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Once I know how to add other linearlayouts I'm good I think, thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what is going wrong? What is the problem?

Comment: Look at the example I need to make it without the static XML

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731487/how-to-add-views-to-linear-layout

Comment: Not really, I need to know how to add 3 linearlayouts into a parent linearlayout without an XML file.

Comment: Well... you could **get rid of all 4** LinearLayouts and use a **single** RelativeLayout, instead, which helps **lowering the layout count** (for **better performance**).

Answer (score 0):

`LinearLayout` is itself a subclass of `View`, so you can add it as a child to other `LinearLayouts`.

Like so:

```
LinearLayout horizontalLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
horizontalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

LinearLayout verticalLayout1 = new LinearLayout(this);
verticalLayout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
LinearLayout verticalLayout2 = new LinearLayout(this);
verticalLayout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

horizontalLayout.addView(verticalLayout1);
horizontalLayout.addView(verticalLayout2);
```

Just populate your first and third vertical layout with buttons as you do in your loop.

Hope this helps.